# How can I mock a view/controller using NUnit and Moq?

Tags: c#, sqlite, nunit, moq

I have a C# application(it is a Cocoa application) and I need to test the view/controller using NUnit and Moq, and it is a little difficult. More exactly, I have a layered application, connected to sqlite-net database. I  want to test the add method. This is one of my tables :

```
public class User
{
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public String email { get; set; }
        public String password { get; set; 
}
```

I created a DBContext for this, in which I create the database, tables and connect to the database. Being a layered application, I also have UserRepo and UserBusinessLogic in which I make all the queries. My question is, how can I test the addUser operation? I need to mention I am using sqlite-pcl-net as database framework.
I already tried this:

```
var mock = new Mock<IUserBLL>();
            User user = new User
            {
                email = "a@yahoo.com",
                password = "1234",

            };
var controller = new CreateController(mock.Object);
```

But my test fails with a null exception when trying to create a controller. I am thinking of a setup for mock? This is my controller:

```
public partial class CreateController : NSViewController
{
IUserBLL userBLL;

public CreateAccountController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
{
   Initialize();
   userBLL = new UserBLL();
}
/* I AM USING THIS ONE */
public CreateAccountController(IUserBLL userBLL) : base()
{
   Initialize();
   this.userBLL = userBLL;
}
```

I need to test the controller and it's methods, not just the methods from database.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any other requirements for your controller's constructor besides an instance of IUserBLL? Does `Initialize()` or the underlying NSViewContoller class reference ore require anything that is not available or instantiated during this test?

As a side note, the lone "user" variable you are creating is not getting used at all. Make sure you're approaching this test from the angle of "Arrange, Act, Assert". Once you've set up the pieces, what action on the controller are you trying to test? What do you assert should be the result of that action on your mocked repository?

**Edited:**
Based on your additional code, it's apparent the guess at ASP NET Core MVC based on the `new Controller()` was wrong (looks like you're using Xamarin) so removing the links.

Comment: It is indeed just a part of my code. From here forward it is just a method trying to perform click from controller and some asserts, and the user variable is added using mock.object.add(user). However, I still have a null exception when trying to create the controller...

Comment: If that's the case, you may need to provide more of your test code and the controller you are trying to instantiate. Based solely on what you've posted, the only obvious candidate is the use of  `new Controller()` as opposed to `new MySpecificController()`

Comment: I am starting to understand that this goes to null exception because I only use IuserBll which is an interface and even though I use the mock I don't instantiate or setup UserBll.. Do you have any idea how to correct this?

Comment: Mocking against an interface is the right way to go for a unit test, and your code updates made it a little clearer you weren't talking about ASP NET MVC controllers, too. If you have not, put some breakpoints in your test and Debug the test instead of running it. Does it actually fail on the line where you instantiate it? If so, does the stack trace give any indications of what specifically is causing a null exception during creation?

Comment: Yes, I am sure..Never passes over the controller, and this is why the test fails: System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: obj

Comment: Ah, now you're getting somewhere. What happens if you debug the test with breakpoints inside your controller constructor on the Initialize() method as well as the passed in parameter? What is the Initialize() method doing and is it possible its doing some service-locator-y stuff that might be failing? 

You can be sure it's not your IUserBLL instance by adding a specific exception to the assignment in your constructor: `this.userBLL = userBLL ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userBLL)); // Will give you a very explicit error message in the exception`

Comment: so.. Given the stack trace I just realized that the problem is with NSViewController's constructor, because tries to create a new controller and the argument is intptr, which is going to the pointer of the storyboard but since the view is not going it is always going null

Comment: I posted a new question trying with a new controller, maybe you could help with that one..

Answer (score 0):

For this case is better to use in memory database. Your case should be something like this

```
//Create MemoryDB
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "AddUserDb").Options;
var dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext(options);
// Initialize service
var service = new IUserBLL();
// Get AddUser function
service.AddUser();
```

Comment: I would need to test the controller, not just the methods from database..